# Convert HTML JavaScript template to angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a template in HTML and CSS and Javascript. I split HTML and CSS to components but I cannot adopt javascript to angular.

In this template has a lot of javascript at the bottom of body. and designer assumed at that point all of the view loaded completely. but it did not happen. How can adopt it with angular?

For example, my designer set all dropdowns event but at bottom of body, any dropdown doesn't exist.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. To me it's entirely unclear what this question is about.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i explain my purpose

Comment: That didn't help. Talk is cheap. Show me the code. (Linus Torvalds) https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds#2000-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If im understanding you correctly, your javascript is loading before your DOM has completed rendering the elements you are trying to change. As I dont have your original code, if this truly is the issue you should look into Angular 2 lifecycle hooks.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

I would try putting this at the top of your file

```
import {AfterContentInit}
```

appending this to your class declaration

```
implements AfterContentInit
```

and then running your javascript inside of this function

```
ngAfterContentInit()
{
// your javascript here
}
```

Comment: yes exactly right. but the problem is the javascript code is too much and  I can't use javascript in typescript.

Comment: typescript is just syntax , when youre using angular2, almost all of the templating and js is handled through a transpiler which convert it to javascript. 
Now when you say that the code is "too much"  you mean dont like the amount of code ? the code is slowing down your application? 

There are no file size limits. but you cannot use inline javascript in the angular2 template. It must be part of the exported class. If what you need is to pass a large amount of js into your app for global use.. similar to a js plugin you can use a script tag in ur index.html. you may also import external js

Comment: as he said, its difficult to really determine your need without seeing the code but it does sound like a problem that can be easily solved by placing the js in the appropriate place. If you need a reference the official site shows you how to use JS using TypeScript for all of its examples